# How to make application loading independent of web service call?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have created a phonegap app which calls a web service on initialization (onload of index.html). I am making the call using

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://webserviceurl.com/service",
  cache: false,
  async: true, 
  success: onSuccess,
  error: onError,
  timeout: 40000
});
```

Now if the webservice is not available, the service call waits for 40 seconds (limit I set as timeout) and transfers the control to onError message, which inturn shows a simple alert message for error.

But my problem is, app shows a blank screen and doesn't show the html page untill the service call finishes (40 seconds). I want the webservice call to execute at backend and doesn't effect loading of actual app (I thought async:true will help, but that does not).

Any ideas how can I make my app independent of webservice call?

**Edit**
This worked

```
function appReady(){
      // do the ajax here
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);
```

Comment: if this is in an onLoad() event, the page will first be loaded, displayed and only then the AJAX call is made - you sure you have anything on the page itself? this should definitelly NOT stop index.html from displaying, since that is a local file, while this is an external call - they are separate and don't block each other

Comment: also, are you sure this is not because of a cross-site request? perhaps you forgot to set $.support.cors = true; and it's generating a JS error for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do that like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://webserviceurl.com/service",
  cache: false,
  async: true, 
  success: onSuccess,
  error: onError,
  timeout: 40000
});

});
```

Now your ajax query will be made after document is ready (fully loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up your page before making the call.